# Raphael - data added to element changing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, parameters, raphael

This is going to be one of those where everyone is like "show us some code" and I have to be like "sorry the relevant code is about 300 lines long". So I'll give as much detail as I can. Ask questions, come up with crazy ideas, at this point even a hint in the right direction will save me some hair.

I'm using Raphaeljs to create some arc segments. No big deal, works great! I'm creating several at a time in a `for` loop, and assigning them a 'reference angle' (among other things) as 'data', so that I know the angle that was used to calculate them in other functions later.

VERY Shortened version:

```
//pieces being the number of arcs I'm creating
for (var i = 0; i < pieces; ++i){
    var refAngle = foo + bar;
    var my_arc = paper.path().attr({
        arc: [foo, bar, etc]
    });
    my_arc.node.cmdata = params[0][i];
    my_arc.node.cmdata[4] = refAngle;
    //when checked here, my_arc.node.cmdata[4] === refAngle and is the value I am looking for
}
```

`Params` is a multi-level array of static data used to draw the arcs. The refAngle needs to be modified, as the arcs are moved if they were going to render off screen, and may not meet the `params` value any longer.

I can confirm 100% that the correct angle is being calculated. I can confirm 100% that the correct angle is stored. I can confirm 100% that immediately after storing it, it can be retrieved correctly. But, in a consistent manner (if I perform the same operation I get the same results), in one or more of the later loops, SOME of the previously created arcs are getting their `my_arc.node.cmdata[4]` changed - I've found this logging all the created arc's `my_arc.node.cmdata[4]` property in each iteration on the `for` loop.

This... doesn't make any sense. I don't know if it's Raphael doing something (shouldn't be) or if I'm losing my mind (totes possible), but that data shouldn't be changing. This is a test page I'm working on, so there's no other functions being called whatsoever that could interfere with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Randy, quick question for you: when this is happening, is the data changing to a single value across the board, or are most of the values right with only a few outliers, or is it random?  Have you characterized the nature of the data disturbance at all?  Also: are there any animations in the full version not expressed here?

Comment: @KevinNielsen There are animations, and I know what you're thinking there: but that's not it. The animations are encapsulated and stored for later use. And it's definitely NOT random, the same arcs are getting mixed up every time I run it, but with no particular pattern. I THINK that, since some of the arcs are referenced using the same value in the master array, that these are simply a reference and NOT a copy, so that the master array may be changing and therefor throwing off anything referenced to it. Will check and get back!